# Correct value of a CheckBox in Jquery DataTable does not get sent back to MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple JQuery DataTable with two columns where one of them is CheckBox:

```
    columns: [
    { "width": "1%", "className":"dt-body-left", 'data': "name" },
    {
        "width": "5%",
        'data':   "status",
        "render": function (data, type, row){
            if (type === 'display'){
                return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active" name="chkbx1" value="col0">';            
            }
            return data;               
        },
        className: "dt-body-left"
    },
    ]
```

Here is one way how user changes CheckBox status:

```
$("#changeStatus").on('click', function()
{
    var rowId = $("#example").dataTable()
                .fnFindCellRowIndexes("mytest", 0);

            if(rowId.length)
            {
                var table = $("#example").DataTable();
                var chkbx1 = $(table.cell( rowId, 1).node()).find('input[name="chkbx1"]');
                chkbx1.prop("checked", true);
                console.log("Yes");
            }
            else{
                console.log("No");
            }
})
```

Then I would like to send data from this table back to controller:

```
$("#sendToController").on('click', function()
{
    var dataArray = [];
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var data = table.rows().data();
    data.each(function (value, index) {
                 dataArray.push(
                 {
                     Name: value.name,
                     Status: value.status,
                 });
    });

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: "/Home/StartCheckTest",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(dataArray),
        success: function (event){}
    })
});
```

Here is receiving method:

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> StartCheckTest([FromBody] List<ResultsViewModel> text)
    {
        //DoStuff();
    }
```

And here is the model:

```
public class ResultsViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when I send this data back to Controller, it does not matter what status CheckBox is in , I always get value 1. I suspect that the problem could be related to conversion from checked state to int, but I am new to ASP.NET MVC and can not figure it out.

Comment: I can't see any connection between the rendered HTML and the data `status`.

Comment: Don't check what data your controller sees as that's after all the various model binding that MVC does.  Instead, check what data is being *sent*.   eg `console.log(dataArray)` and/or browser network tab (F12).

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you for showing interest. If I log dataArray, this is what I get:Object { Name: "mytest", Status: 1 } in both cases. I will edit my answer to show how I set the checkBox value, if that is what you ment in your  previous comment.

Comment: Your update shows that you're changing the DOM element, not the underlying datatable data.   You'll find this sort of issue goes away if you separate (in your head) the data from the representation of it.  With jquery/js, we're used to changing the DOM then reading the DOM to get the values.   With datatables, the DOM is just the representation of the data, not the data itself.  Change the data directly, then tell datatables to refresh the representation.

Comment: @freedomn-m I am a bit confused. Do you mean like this? table.cell(rowId, 1).data(1).draw();